# Sikuli lags after big while loop

Tags: python, sikuli

I have a while loop that runs 200 times and clicks on a button.
After running about 90 times it gets about 8 times as slow all of a sudden. So the while loop works great but it just starts lagging for no reason.

```
i = 200
while i!= 0:
    click(img)
    sleep(1)
    print i
    i-=1
```

I have no clue how this can happen. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I also have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the post [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/1739534).

You may try running `<path to your setup folder>/runsikulix -r yourScript.sikuli` instead of running the script using sikuli IDE if you encounter this problem in MacOS.

Comment: I don't own my Mac anymore. Did anyone try this so I can set this as the right answer? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Oh I see you had the same problem. I will set this as the best answer then.

Answer (score 0):

It may because of your processor speed. Better use high speed processor.

use wait() instead of sleep(). you will get different performance

Comment: I see what you mean but why after about 90 times?

Tried wait first, then tried sleep. Same problem. I think it happens faster with sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
i = 200 
imgLoc = find("image.png")
while i != 0:
    imgLoc.click()
    wait(1)
    print(i)
    i = i -1
```

In your code the line `click(img)` is constantly looking for the image on the screen. 
 
What is more efficient is to first find the image, that way we now it's location. 
 
Then click the image x times. 
 
This makes the code faster if you do this for example 200 times.

Also I believe `wait()` is going faster on some computers. 
 
Don't ask me why though....